# Rails: Define default values from variable in a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'd like to initiate a new record with some default values.

```
@test = "#{@fb_page['id']}, slug: #{slug}, title: #{@fb_page['name']}"
@frame = Frame.new(:fb_page_id => @fb_page['id'].to_i, :slug => slug, :title => @fb_page['name'], :theme => 'default')
```

@test shows all I want:

```
<the-page-id>, slug: mrs-test, title: Mrs. Test
```

But a few of the default values for the @frame are nil!

```
# @frame.inspect: 
#<Frame id: nil, slug: nil, title: "Mrs. Test", theme: "default", fb_page_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Could anyone please explain me why it doesn't take some of the variables? The string "default" gets through as well as`@fb_page['name']`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This typically happens when you don't list those attributes under the `attr_accessible` section of the model.

```
attr_accessible :fb_page_id, :slug, :title, :theme
```

Rails has [mass-assignment protection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) to prevent malicious users from mass-assigning certain model attributes.  So when you pass in attributes to a `Model.new()` method, the only attributes that will persist will be ones that are listed in `attr_accessible` (unless you haven't protected your models yet).

If you want to leave those attributes protected (as they currently are), you need to set those attributes using dot notation:

```
@frame = Frame.new
@frame.fb_page_id = @fb_page['id'].to_i
@frame.slug = slug
@frame.title = @fb_page['name']
@frame.theme = 'default'
```

Comment: Awesome! Your are too good! That was exactly the point! My slug was originaly named 'unique_name' and that was in the list of attr_accessible. Thanks a lot! Also good to know that I would have made it with dot notation. Because I thougth I can assigne all attributes but not from 'outside'. Thanks!!!